# $\mathbb{C}[f(x)]$ is not a maximal subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

> Prove that $\mathbb{C}[f(x)]$ is not a maximal subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ for all $f\in\mathbb C[x] $.

I managed to prove it in a straightforward way by taking $f(x)=a_0 + a_1x+\cdots+ a_nx^n$ and by means of contradiction. But I am looking for a more elegant solution that is not brute force. (It must be extremely easy but without sleep my brain is in a standstill).

Comment: Does "for all $f$" mean "for some $f$"?  Just take $f(x) = x^2$ and you have an example. If you meant something other than that, please rewrite the premise of the question.

Comment: Rschwieb, you are exactly right. Probably it is not entirely clear. What I mean is that $\mathbb{C}[f(x)]$ cannot be a maximal subring of $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

Comment: @KCd I think the question is clear, maybe the for all $f$ should had been at the beginning of the question... Maybe "For each $f$ prove that..." might had been a clearer phrasing, keep in mind that not everyone is English native speaker though...

Comment: The user's attempt of using contradiction makes it seem that the statement was meant to be $\forall f(\neg \phi)$, but the written order suggests $\neg\forall f(\phi)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for $\deg(f)=0,1$ we have $C[f] =C$ or $C[f]=C[x]$, we will only worry about the case $\deg(f) \geq 2$.

Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $f(x)$. Then $\mathbb C[f(x)]$ is a subring of $\mathbb C[f(x)]+I$.

Since $\deg(f) \geq 2$ it is easy to prove that $x \notin \mathbb C[f(x)]+I$, thus $\mathbb C[f(x)]+I \neq \mathbb C[x]$. Also $xf(x) \in I$ thus $xf(x) \in \mathbb C[f(x)]+I$ but not in $\mathbb C[f(x)]$.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant with "elegant solution". Thanks.

Comment: When did $\deg(f)\geq 2$ come into the picture? I didn't see it mentioned. I was thinking that the cases of degrees 0 and 1 would be included too. They are easily done away with, of course...

Comment: @rschwieb The cases $\deg(f)=0$ or $1$ are trivial, since in those cases we know $C[f(x)]$.

Comment: @N.S. Yes, I said they are easily dealt with. You didn't mention it though. "Since <hypothesis nobody mentioned>" would probably be better as "For 0 and 1 things are easy, so WLOG $deg(f)\geq 2$..."

Comment: I agree with rschwieb: the problem should have been written as "Show for each $f(x)$ of *degree not* $1$ that ${\mathbf C}[f(x)]$ is not a maximal subring of ${\mathbf C}[x]$." Even though it's clear that the case  of degree $1$ was not intended, that's not a good reason to leave out a hypothesis whose absence makes the result incorrect.

Comment: @KCd If $\deg(f)=1$ then $C[f(x)]=C[x]$ which is NOT maximal subring of $C[x]$. By definition, maximal is a proper subring.....

Comment: Oops, good point. Fair enough: for all $f(x)$...